# Returning a value based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a situation where there are 2 tables set up on 2 sheets of the workbook. Table one looks like

```html
<table style="width:50%">
  <tr>
    <th>Zone</th>
    <th>Journey</th> 
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>Return</td> 
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>Single</td> 
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And the second looks like

```html
<table style="width:30%">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Return</th> 
    <th>Single</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>250</td> 
    <td>165</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>305</td> 
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>355</td> 
    <td>230</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The scenario is:
I want to bring the price back by looking at the Zone and if it is a return or single journey. So for the top row on sheet 1 it would be Zone A, Return, 250.

I thought of trying to combine a nested if and a vlookup all in one go, but don't think this will work. Is there a way to get the desired result? If there isn't a formula solution, could a VBA macro be used instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your provided sample data, on Sheet1, cell K2, use this formula and copy down:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$B:$C,MATCH(I2,Sheet2!$A:$A,0),MATCH(J2,Sheet2!$B$1:$C$1,0))
```

Comment: Thank you very much - I just couldn't get my head around it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If your table on sheet1 is in cells A1 to C4 and your "look up" pricing table is in sheet2 cells A1 to C5 then I would put the following formula into cell C2 on sheet 1:

```
=VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet2!$A$1:$C$5,MATCH(B3,Sheet2!$A$1:$C$1,0),FALSE)
```

Not meaning to step on @tigeravatar's toes!  Its an alternative to his solution - not sure there is any advantage of one over the other!